# Why am I getting 84.25 instead of 97.68 for my Confidence Interval?

Tags: statistics, education, statistical-inference

[image]

Why am I getting 84.25. I am doing 97.96*(6/sqrt[50-1]) = 97.96*(6/7) I am obviously not doing this correctly please help. It has been sometime since I have done any math.

Comment: Order of operations requires that you first perform the multiplication of $1.96$ and $6/7$, followed by addition to $96$.

Comment: HAHAHAHA Omg! I feel like such an idiot. This stat class has me frazzled. Thank you!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are doing $$\left(96+1.96\right) \left(\dfrac{6}{\sqrt{50-1}}\right)$$ when you should be doing $$96+\left(1.96 \left(\dfrac{6}{\sqrt{50-1}}\right)\right).$$

As separate points: $97.68$ is roughly the $0.975$ quantile not the $0.95$ quantile; a confidence interval should have a lower value too, so the $95\%$ confidence interval should be $[94.32,97.68]$

Comment: Thank You as well! facepalm.jpg